# geom_ribbon() Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale (ggplot2)

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I've tried searching for a solution to this seemingly easy problem, but to no avail. All I'm trying to do is plot a line in ggplot and its standard deviation around the line. However, I keep recovering this error:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

My data frame `plotdata` is as follows:

```
 sites    Spoly     Spolylower Spolyupper
 526.790 0.03018671 0.1196077 0.1196077
1538.512 0.04106053 0.1429613 0.1429613
2540.500 0.02896953 0.1127456 0.1127456
3541.000 0.03560484 0.1200609 0.1200609
4560.143 0.06038193 0.1564464 0.1564464
5569.831 0.03608714 0.1296704 0.1296704
```

I can plot just the line perfectly fine:

```
ggplot(data = plotdata, aes(x = "Sites", y = "Mean Values")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = sites, y = Spoly), color = "steelblue")
```

But when I try to add the ribbon, I get the error:

```
ggplot(data = plotdata, aes(x = "Sites", y = "Mean Values")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = sites, y = Spoly), color = "steelblue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = sites, ymin = Spolylower, ymax = Spolyupper), alpha = 0.3)

Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

What is going on? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

one option is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
data <- "
sites    Spoly     Spolylower Spolyupper
526.790 0.03018671 0.1196077 0.1196077
1538.512 0.04106053 0.1429613 0.1429613
2540.500 0.02896953 0.1127456 0.1127456
3541.000 0.03560484 0.1200609 0.1200609
4560.143 0.06038193 0.1564464 0.1564464
5569.831 0.03608714 0.1296704 0.1296704
"
dat <- read.table(text = data, header = TRUE)
#change Spolylower value (currently Spolylower= Spolyupper)
dat$Spolylower <- dat$Spolylower - .2

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = sites, y = Spoly)) +
      geom_line(color = "steelblue") +
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Spolylower, ymax = Spolyupper), alpha = 0.3) +
      theme_cowplot()
```

Comment: you could also do: `ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_line(aes(x = sites, y = Spoly), color = "steelblue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = sites, ymin = Spolylower, ymax = Spolyupper), alpha = 0.3)` which might be cleaner and easier to understand. The problem with the original OP was trying to name x and y: `ggplot(data = plotdata, aes(x = "Sites", y = "Mean Values"))`. It should be variable names in the call and then add labels after using `labs`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
ggplot(data = plotdata, aes(x = "Sites", y = "Mean Values")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = sites, y = Spoly), color = "steelblue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = plotdata$Spolylower, ymax = plotdata$Spolyupper),fill="dimgray", alpha = 0.1)
```

let me know if it works